# Engine for use with PC and Iphone?

Tags: iphone, windows

Are there any engines that allow me to develop for pc and iphone at the same time?  My preferred language would be c#, but that probably won't happen, so I probably will learn c++ or java.

I want a 2d engine, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No experience with it but...

http://www.torquepowered.com/products/torque-2D/

Answer (score 0):

C# and Java aren't allowed on the iPhone, so a C or C++ engine would be your best bet.  I'm guessing  you're doing a game--if so, you'll probably want to use OpenGL.  I don't know any specifically, but [here's a full list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines).

Comment: There are a few engines out there that compile down to iPhone native code so it is possible to write in languages other than C, C++ or Objective C... however if you have been paying attention to the news these platforms may no longer be allowed to be used due to the new terms of service in OS 4.

Answer (score 0):

Working with pure Core Animation layers can yield cross-platform 2-D drawing and animation between iPhone, iPad, and Mac.  As an example of this, the [Core Plot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) runs on Mac and iPhone from the same codebase.  Core Animation lets you do some pretty complex animations and layout in 2-D.

Answer (score 0):

It is against the rules in OS 4 to write an iPhone app in something other than Apple's dev tools. However, IANAL but I'd expect that it is in theory ok to take the app you made there and then try to run it on an emulation layer etc.. on the /other/ platform(s). Not sure about direct solutions, but check out the GNU Objective-C runtime / GNUStep, they might be a helpful starting point.